# biblatex: no linebreaks in name lists when typesetting ragged-right

Tags: biblatex, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, paragraphs

When typesetting a bibliography `\raggedright,` `biblatex` seems to have trouble breaking a line between an author's first/last/middle names (and, if multiple authors are present, between two authors). It's as if the entire name list had been put into an `\mbox`.
Consider this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,DIV=6]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tgschola}

\begin{filecontents}{bibtest.bib}
@COLLECTION{Star95,
  editor = {Star, Susan Leigh},
  year = {1995},
  title = {Ecologies of Knowledge: Work and Politics in Science and Technology},
  address = {Albany},
  publisher = {SUNY}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Star95a,
  author = {Star, Susan Leigh},
  title = {The Politics of Formal Representations: Wizards, Gurus, and Organizational
    Complexity},
  year = {1995},
  pages = {88-118},
  crossref = {Star95}
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}
\bibliography{bibtest.bib}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
\noindent\hrule
\nocite{Star95a}
\printbibliography
\noindent\hrule
\end{document}
```

»Susan Leigh« would easily fit into the fourth line, but instead her entire name is moved to the next one. It would seem odd to me that this should be `biblatex's` intended behavior, as it can have even worse results under certain circumstances. Can you reproduce this? What would be a way to change it? Should I contact the biblatex team?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\RaggedRight` from `\usepackage{ragged2e}`

Comment: `\Raggedright` is what I've been using for years, and what I'm trying to get away from now, as I've decided I like my bibliographies better with no hyphenation at all (as opposed to a hyphenation that only occurs occasionally, but is often awkward). The problem described does not appear when hyphenation is allowed, which is why I didn't notice it until now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line breaks in names are controlled by the `lownamepenalty` and `highnamepenalty` counters. From `biblatex.def` the default values are:

```
\defcounter{lownamepenalty}{\hyphenpenalty/2}
\defcounter{highnamepenalty}{\hyphenpenalty}
```

where `\hyphenpenalty` defaults to `50`.
To allow breaks between the first and last name parts (e.g. "Susan Leigh" and "Star"), you can set `lownamepenalty` to a small value in your preamble. For example:

```
\defcounter{lownamepenalty}{0}
```

Note that `\bibsetup` by default executes a variety of commands. So instead of

```
\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}
```

you're better off with:

```
\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}
```