# Hyphenation in bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation

The hyphenation in my bibliography is off somehow, I can't figure out why. Look:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,hyperref=true]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Fowler:2006,
    Address = {Boston},
    Author = {Fowler, Martin},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    Title = {Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture},
    Year = {2006}}

@book{Rotem-Gal-Oz:2012,
    Address = {Shelter Island, NY},
    Author = {{Rotem-Gal-Oz}, Arnon},
    Publisher = {Manning Publications Co.},
    Title = {SOA Patterns},
    Year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Fowler:2006} \nocite{Rotem-Gal-Oz:2012}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now, when you compile that you can see that the "Addison-" of "Addison-Wesley" is too long. (I put in another Bib-Entry for your reference). 
[image: Addison is to long.]

I could fix this with `Add\-ison` but that's just weird. Also, I have more than one occurrence in my file and I dislike having to check for this error again and again.

So, what do I do now?

Comment: LaTeX hyphenates words with hyphen only at the hyphen. You could use the command `\hyphen` offered by biblatex instead of the -.

Comment: In fact, I see the same issue with non-hyphenated words as well. Example: 
    `@book{Vossen:1996, 
    Address = {Bonn},
    Author = {Vossen, Gottfried AND Becker, J{\"o}rg.},
    Isbn = {978-3826601248},
    Keywords = {Gesch{\"a}ftsprozesse, Definitionen},
    Publisher = In\-ter\-na\-tion\-al Thomson Publ.,
    Title = {Gesch{\"a}ftsproze{\ss}modellierung und Work\-flow-Management. - Modelle, Methoden, Werkzeuge.},
    Year = {1996}}`

The "Thomson" is not hyphenated correctly and too long. 
see: [Picture of Thomson too long](http://i.imgur.com/cbbbZ9X.jpg)

Comment: The word `Thomson` is hyphenated correctly in the picture you've linked in the comment. You could try issuing the command `\sloppy` right before `\printbibliography` to let TeX find a different way to break lines. Alternatively, consider loading the package `ragged2e` and issuing the command `\RaggedRight` before `\printbibliography`.

Comment: @Mico \sloppy worked perfectly fine. I'll go with that, thank you. You might post that as an answer I can "accept".

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109914/no-hyphens-in-biblatex/109917#109917

Comment: since their paragraphs are so short, bibliographies are difficult to set fully justified, even with hyphenation enabled -- and enabling hyphenation is likely going to cause new problems, as bibliographies tend to contain a lot of odd words that TeX finds difficult to hyphenate (author names, cities, companies, publishers...). Is there a reason you can't just use `\raggedright?`

Comment: @NilsL `\raggedright` would have the desired effect, yes. There is no real reason that would keep me from using it, except that I dislike having a bibliography that looks that much different from my text. 
So: Does it work - yes. Do I like it - sorry, no. :)

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this posting as it is *not* a duplicate of the earlier posting. Whereas the subject of the earlier posting was about how to go about suppressing hyphenation entirely while using `biblatex`, the present posting is about how to avoid overfull lines when LaTeX (not biblatex) is set not to hyphenate the component words in a hyphenated compound word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When dealing with material that's difficult to hyphenate, it can help at times -- but it's not guaranteed to work under all circumstances -- to provide the directive `\sloppy`. The `\sloppy` instruction lets TeX find line breaks by widening the amount of inter-word whitespace far more than is (normally) considered to be tolerable. However, do be sure to exhaust other possibilities before resorting to using `\sloppy` -- the results you may get with this method may look, well, sloppy!

Comment: To be honest, I think this is a perfect solution for bibliographies. It might not help all the time but it did for me without exceptions.

Comment: How do you cancel the effects of `\sloppy` when more sections follow the bibliography?

Comment: @m000 - `\fussy`.

Comment: how can I check whether `\sloppy` is still active?

Comment: @FrederickNord - Not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking if there's a TeX conditional that's set to "true" if `\sloppy` is in force?

Comment: I guess I care more about the typesetting result than about programmatically asking for the status. But yeah, a conditional would tell me, whether `\sloppy` has accidentally been left on. I guess it manipulates some internal settings which could be queried for.