# References not respecting margins with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, margins, biber, hyphenation

I am using `biblatex` with the `biber` backend for my bibliography. The problem I encountered is that margins are not always respected. It seems to be a fairly common issue, cf. these possibly related questions (answers do not apply as far as I can tell):

- [References in margins `biblatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70851/references-in-margins-biblatex)
- [References spilling out of margin in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196122/references-spilling-out-of-margin-in-bibliography)

### Repro code

I used the `showframe` package to help visualize the spilling.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@article{cheng:ijrr:2004,
    author = {Cheng, Peng and LaValle, Steven M.},
    journal = {International Journal of Robotics Research},
    pages = {1--37},
    title = {{Resolution completeness for sampling-based motion planning with differential constraints}},
    year = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{cheng:ijrr:2004}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Reference spilling in margin]

So how can I solve this? Who's the culprit here? Is there workaround for this issue?

Comment: add `\usepackage{microtype}` in your preamble. I might help.

Comment: [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706) and [Why can words with hyphen char not be hyphenated?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232)

Comment: @pluton: it did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the pointers, I added the `hyphenation` tag since that seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Microtype has no effect with the `draft` option.

Comment: @pluton: oh that's why! I still have a bit of spilling though, but it does seem slightly better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Johannes_B pointed out, the issue is with the hyphenation. Possible workarounds involve `\raggedright` (see [No hyphens in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109914/no-hyphens-in-biblatex)) or `\sloppy` (see [Hyphenation in bibliography with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118068/hyphenation-in-bibliography-with-biblatex)).

With `\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}`:

[image]

With `\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}`:

[image]

Comment: or directly write samp\-ling, or maybe sam\-pling in your bib file.

Comment: In this particular case the problem is that words already containing a hyphen cannot be hyphenated anywhere except at the hyphen. So `sampling-based` only breaks at the `-`. It may already help to add the possible break-points `sampling` and `based` back in manually. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/35864. (This is mentioned in the comments under the question that this answer refers to, but it might still be good to have it mentioned here explicitly.)

Comment: For more help on general line breaking problems, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864